# How to delete a task in react functional component hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to delete a task using `handleDelete` function, but something get my attention and i don't know why!
Every time i press the addTodos function, the `handleDelete` is triggered automatically why is that ?

My aim is to get the id once i press a tag inside the map, but as a weird thing to a beginner as myself i don't know why once i press the Add button the `handleDelete` function runs ?

My code :

```
     import { useState } from "react";
     import "./App.scss";

      function App() {
        //Value of Input
        const [val, setVal] = useState("");

      const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

      const addTodos = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setTodos([...todos, val]);
          setVal("");
       };

      const handleDelete = (id) => {
          console.log(id);
       };

      return (
        <div className="App">
        {/** On change values*/}
       <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
             onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
             value={val}
             type="text"
         />
         <button type="submit">Add</button>
       </form>
       <ul>
          {todos.map((todo, key) => (
           <div key={key}>
              <li>{todo}</li>
              <a onClick={handleDelete(key)}>X</a>
           </div>
            ))}
       </ul>
      </div>
      );
      }

      export default App;
```

I tried to console log inside the id inside handleDelete function but the console is also triggered from the `addTodos`  function as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```js
onClick={handleDelete(key)}>X</a>
// handleDelete(key) gets called immediately and returns `undefined`
// this means it will delete the task immediately and try to execute
// `undefined` on the 'click' event
```

To this:

```js
onClick={()=> handleDelete(key)}>X</a>
// An arrow function is passed as an event handler to the onClick event
// this means it will be executed on the 'click' event only
```

In the first case, you are calling the function handleDelete and pass its return value as an event handler.

In the second case, you are passing an arrow function expression as an event handler, which is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, but could you please explain what is the difference in this case ?

Comment: The difference is that in the first example, instead of creating a callback to call a function when someone clicks, you just perform that action right away. So handleDelete will be called before a user clicks. And in the second example, only the callback function will be created. However, actual action will be performed when a user clicks

Comment: Thank you both guys for explaining much appreciated